# When I click a button, I get the error: Attempt to call function 'show' in base 'null instance' on a null instance

Tags: button, scene, godot, gdscript

I'm relatively new to game development with Godot, and I'm working on making a title screen for a small indie game. I made a button that takes you to an about page within the game, and I'm working on an exit button for the about page. I used close to the same code that functions for the title screen. It looks like this:

```
extends Button

#Scripts

func _on_exit_pressed():
    print ("exit pressed")
    $frontblackabout.show()
    $frontblackabout/exitTimer.start()


func _on_exitTimer_timeout():
    print ("exit timer done")
    get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/menu.tscn")
```

For some reason, after it gives me an error on the seventh line [$frontblackabout.show()], it gives me the error: Attempt to call function 'show' in base 'null instance' on a null instance.
I've tried everything I can think of and nothing works.

Also for some more info, $frontblackabout is a ColorRect that is hidden in the current scene.

Comment: For what I've seen, most cases are a wrong node path. And the rest are some instancing issue (you instanced the script but should have instanced the scene, or there should be only one instance but there are multiple and this code is running in the wrong one, stuff like that), edit: ah, and the occasional case of some other code removing the node. I cannot tell what the case is with the information provided.

Comment: i dont know why but after messing with the code it started working. i assuming it was the wrong node path as you said. as I messed around with the node arrangements previously. thank you for your help nonetheless.